# How to write NOT in query in CakePHP find?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have created one SQL sub-query which was running perfectly.

```
SELECT o.*, u.*,OD.* FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_details OD on o.id = OD.order_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.id 
WHERE o.order_status = 1 AND o.id NOT IN 
   (SELECT r.order_id FROM order_rejected_details r WHERE r.courier_id =$courierId) 
order by o.id desc
```

How to write above query with `NOT` in condition in CakePHP?

Comment: What you have tried so far in the Cakephp? have you checked any tutorial for the same?

Comment: i try to create but i dont know how to create nested query or not in condition in cakephp

Comment: so your letting other(s) coding that for you instead of asking for help about a bug , etc... it's better you look for a tutorial or documentation about how to use query builder in cakephp first

Comment: You need to check notMatching http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-notmatching

Comment: which version of cake you using?

Comment: The only complexity in the question is `NOT IN (SELECT..` the rest is pretty standard. Please add to the question your attempt to write a query without that - i.e. demonstrate you've tried _something_. Note the above comment also.

Comment: (Side note: make sure `$courierId` is cast to integer or is not user-tainted - otherwise you may have a SQL injection vuln in your application).

Answer (score -2):

You can simply write this query in CakePHP as per below.

In model:

```
$resultData = $this->query('SELECT o.*, 
       u.*, 
       OD.* 
FROM   orders o 
       LEFT JOIN order_details OD 
              ON o.id = OD.order_id 
       LEFT JOIN users u 
              ON o.user_id = u.id 
WHERE  o.order_status = 1 
       AND o.id NOT IN (SELECT r.order_id 
                        FROM   order_rejected_details r 
                        WHERE  r.courier_id = $courierid) 
ORDER  BY o.id DESC');

return $resultData;
```

Comment: one can, but this is hardly the answer the OP is expecting. There's no ORM usage/benefits doing that.

Comment: I know there is no benefits, but there is a solution i think.!